# How to add multiple, delimiter based frame decoders in netty...............?

Tags: java, netty, delimiter

I'm using **Netty** to take a stream of string data in this format...

```
               string1#st2|st3|st4..|....|
```

I get multiple blocks of this sort of Strings which are separated by **\n** and I want to first separate those chunks and then the particular strings...

My problem is that if I use a **delimiter based frame decoder** with \n as the delimiter,I can separate the strings without a problem..But how can i separate the rest of the string without using a string tokenizer.... Is there a way to add multiple **delimiter based frame decoders** ? Because I want to first process the information in string1 and then based on that the rest of the string.... If I write a decoder to separate the string1 then there would be no way to separate the rest of the string without using string tokenizing...

Thanx...

Edit

Is there a way to persist an object in the channel.. like in servlet context objects.......

Answer (score 0):

You should be able todo this by just adding two (or more if you need) DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder instances to your ChannelPipeline. Just put the one that does seperate by '\n' first and after that add the other. This should just work..

Comment: Yes I did that and it worked..but the thing is that I want to keep the String1 and then do the decoding to the rest... The problem is that soon after I put a handler to do whatever the logic for string1, it is not possible to put another DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder to decode the rest of the String...

Comment: Sorry I don't get your problem.. Can you try to explain a bit in more detail ?

Comment: What I want to know is that how to put a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder after a another decoder which returns a String...?

Comment: DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder will return a ChannelBuffer at all cases. So I dont see how it could return a String. Anyway if you have a String as input you will need to add another OneToOneDecoder that convert the String to a ChannelBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

In netty 5, you could directly set customized attributes into channel like the context in servlet.

With Channel attributes, you could always process the rest of the string after persisting delimited substrings, maybe a formatted result, through a pipeline of decoders.

Here is a sample could be referenced: [Using channel attributes in different context handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932352/using-channel-attributes-in-different-context-handlers)