# Using channel attributes in different context handlers

Tags: java, netty

I'm working on an application server part of which will be based on Netty 4.0. However, I ran into a problem of shared variables for the channel.
I have read that to use such variables in the other context handlers I need to use

- context.channel().attr(key).set()

instead of just

- context.attr(key).set()

to attach my variable to current channel.
Like here:

```
 public class HadlePackets extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HadlePackets.class);
public AttributeKey<Integer> clientIDattrKey = new AttributeKey<Integer>  ("ClientID");

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object message) throws Exception {
 ...
ctx.channel().attr(clientIDattrKey).set(IDnum); //bind ID to channel

...
}
}
```

But, how do I retrieve the value of a variable in another context the handler? Attribute key is still needed and i cant grab it from handler who attached variable.

```
public class StorageHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StorageSaveHandler.class);

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Integer clientID = (Integer)ctx.channel().attr(null).get(); //How can i get proper key for this channel attribute?
    ctx.fireChannelInactive();

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should work since it is `public static`:

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Integer clientID = (Integer) ctx.channel().attr(HandlePackets.clientIDattrKey).get();
    ctx.fireChannelInactive();
}
```

Here is a little example of how I use it. It is just a code excerpt though:

```
public class NettyServer implements Runnable {
final static AttributeKey<Long> CHECKSUMKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("calcchecksum");
final static AttributeKey<Command> COMMANDKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("command");
final static AttributeKey<Long> FILEHANDLEKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("filehandle");
final static AttributeKey<File> PATHKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("destpath");
final static AttributeKey<FileOutputStream> OUTPUTSTREAM = AttributeKey.valueOf("stream");

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(BOSS_THREADS);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(calculateThreadCount());
        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

            // This option will allow binding to an already bound ip:port
            // combination.
            // This is usually used to be able to restart a server if it
            // crashed/got killed
            // (so while the socket is still in the TIME_WAIT state).
            bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
            bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("ObjectDecoder", new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("ObjectEncoder", new ObjectEncoder());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("CommandHandler", new ServerCommandHandler(server, logger));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("FileHandler", new ServerFileHandler(server, logger));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("ChecksumHandler", new ServerChecksumHandler(server, logger));
                }
            });

            try {
                // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
                bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.debug(Message.CMDTRANSFER_INTERRUPTED_DEBUG, e.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Message.CMDTRANSFER_CONNECT_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

As you can see I have several handlers that share attributes of a channel.

```
public class ServerCommandHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ctx.channel().attr(NettyServer.COMMANDKEY).set(clCommand);
        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    }
}

public class ServerChecksumHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if ctx.channel().attr(NettyServer.COMMANDKEY).getAndRemove() == referenceCommand {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is static indeed. That was my mistake. I need unique ID for every connected client, so it should not be static.
But for every new client channel, netty will create new instance of every ChanelContextHandler. Are they binded around one channel, and if i call Handler A from Handler B it will call Handler for same channel where Handler B is?

Comment: no, no. it's just the key that is static. It can stay like this. You should have access to a channel specific attribute if you set it in your `channelRead` method (like you do) and retrieve it again in your `channelInactive` method